# Diffrent PCA plots

Tags: python, r, pca

I was trying to to learn pca(using the iris dataset) with python and i got some results,so i wanted to test the results ir R to make sure it was good.When i checked the results,it gave me a mirror diagram that of python(in the y axis),and the negative numeric sign in some of the values(python: [140,1]=0.1826089,r[141,2]=-0.1826089[python counts form zero]).

The python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.decomposition as p
data=np.loadtxt("sample_data/iris.txt",delimiter=';',usecols=(0,1,2,3))
pca=p.PCA().fit(data)
pcaData=pca.transform(data)
plt.scatter(pcaData[:,0],pcaData[:,1])
print(pcaData[140,1])
```

[My python diagram](http://prntscr.com/nrrysy)

The R code:

```
data=read.csv("C:\\Users\\George\\Desktop\\iris.csv",sep=";",colClasses=c(NA, NA, NA,NA,"NULL"));data=data[-151,]
pca=prcomp(data)
plot(pca$x[,1],pca$x[,2])
print(pca$x[141,2])
```

[My R diagram](http://prntscr.com/nrrzs2)

In search i did on the internet,i found the same happens.

[The R diagram on the internet](http://prntscr.com/nrrogz)-[Source](https://wilkelab.org/classes/SDS348/2016_spring/worksheets/class9.html)

[The Python diagram on the internet](http://prntscr.com/nrrq7b)-[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60).

I was expecting to be the same.
Is somthing that i do not understand well?

Thank you.

Comment: Apart from @Zoe answer: 
They're _almost_ the same, i.e. they're symmetrical - if you flip one of them upside down, you'll get the other one.
I don't know how much that helps. There might be some slight difference in implementation between R and Python. What is important, from modeling point of view, that this difference doesn't really matter - these new features, obtained via PCA will be equally good for further analysis/modeling. E.g. in linear regression you'd just get corresponding coefficients with different signs.

Answer (score 0):

ScikitLearn uses a pseudo-randomized method to determine an approximation of the singular value decomposition.

see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.extmath.randomized_svd.html

Therefore, unless you can guarantee that the methods are the same and use the same random seed, you will not obtain exactly the same values for the principal components.

Comment: But why isn't PCA a standard method?